# How to make custom slider in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I have a rectangle image and what I want to do is? When I slide the image over the rectangle like slider towards right side then text written on it "swipe me" should become invisible. Along with the range of the slider moving to the right side the text opacity should become 0. It should vary according to the maximum and minimum value of the slider. Also if the slider reaches to the maximum value then it should navigate to the next screen. Is it possible like shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to take a `ToggleSwitch` Style [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709931.aspx) and modify it as you need.

Also, have a look on the [`Slider`](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Basic_Slider_control_in_Windows_Phone) control, you can create a custom style for it. You can bind the text `Opacity` property to slider's `Value` property, so you can easily show-hide the text.